# javascript:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: html

I am new to programming. i am working with kineticjs.while using 'get' property to set opacity of a desired layer. i was caught with that error.

```
squareShapesLastRow2.on('click', function ()
            {
                var highlightspots=[31,14,20,1,33,16,24,5,10,23,8,30,11,36,13,27];
                a=this;
                indexval = highlightspots.indexOf(parseInt(a.attrs.id));
                console.log(indexval);
                for (var i=0;i<(1+1);i++)
                {
                    if(indexval>=highlightspots.length)
                    {
                    indexval=0;
                    }
                    indexval++;
                }
                    for (var j=0;j<(4+1);j++)
                    {
                        if(indexval<0)
                        {
                            indexval=highlightspots.length-1;
                        }
                        else if(indexval>=0)
                        {
                            var shape = a.highlight_layer.get(highlightspots[indexval])[0];
                            shape.setOpacity(1);
                        }
                        a.highlight_layer.draw();
                        indexval--;
                    }
                setTimeout(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < highlightspots.length; i++)
                {
                    var shape = a.highlight_layer.get("#high_" + highlightspots[indexval])[0];
                    shape.setOpacity(.3);
                }
                a.highlight_layer.draw();},1000);
            });
```

Comment: Where are you defining highlight_layer ? Before you use it.. try console.log(a.highlight_layer); if its undefined, there is your problem

Comment: thank you Mauno V for your valid feedback. i fixed that error. the problem is with the 'id' i dint mentioned in the code for referring that high light layer

Comment: The correct way is:var shape = frenchBet.figure.frenchVariables.highlight_layer.get("#"+highlightspots[indexval]+"high")[0];

Answer (score 0):

you should add 'id' for the reference of the mentioned layer.
code rewrite as:
  var shape = a.highlight_layer.get("#"+highlightspots[indexval])[0];